Permanently disable private WiFi MAC for a specific network
I know how to disable the private MAC address for a specific network.
The problem is that iOS 17 stubbornly wants to keep reverting that setting, seemingly at random.  It will stay set with the device's "real" MAC for several days, but then spontaneously reverts to "private WiFi address". This seems to affect some but not all Apple devices.  iPhone SE 3 stays set to non-private; iPhone 13 reverts every few days.
Google searches all return instructions for turning off MAC address randomization, but nothing about why it keeps reverting.
Is there a way to truly permanently disable private addresses for specific WiFi networks?
